# Calling an Activity from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Apologies if this is a dumb question. I have searched for an answer to my problem and although I have found several mentions of this issue, none of the solutions proposed have solved my problem.
In my app, I am calling an Activity from a Fragment and I then want to return to that Fragment via a button click in the Activity.
1 - In fragment Discover_Fragment I have a list view and when one item is pressed, the Activity EditThoughts starts:

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int position, long arg3) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), EditThought.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });
```

Activity EditThoughts starts with no issues. 
2 - Then, when I want to return to the Fragment (Discover_Fragment) from Activity EditThought, I use the following:

```
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    Discover_Fragment fragmentS1 = new Discover_Fragment();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.containerView, fragmentS1)
                            .commit();
```

I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e006e (com.appleia.vocapp:id/containerView) for fragment Discover_Fragment{f1e7d01 #0 id=0x7f0e006e}
```

R.id.containerView is the id for the FrameLayout in activity_main:

```
       <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerView">
       </FrameLayout>
```

The layout for Discover_Fragment is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toplayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/topButtons"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <com.appleia.SegmentedButtons.SegmentedRadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/segment_text"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/button_one"
            android:gravity="center">
            <RadioButton android:id="@id/button_one"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:minWidth="110dp"
                android:minHeight="33dip"
                android:text="@string/Articles"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:button="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@drawable/radio_colors" />
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/button_two"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:minHeight="33dip"
                android:text="Two"
                android:button="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@drawable/radio_colors"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/button_three"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:minWidth="110dp"
                android:minHeight="33dip"
                android:text="@string/Toughts"
                android:button="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@drawable/radio_colors" />
        </com.appleia.SegmentedButtons.SegmentedRadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:layout_below="@+id/toplayout"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can startActivity by calling, `startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)` [docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)). 
After that you can return back to the activity by using `onBackPressed`. If you want to pass any data back to the Activity, then you can use `setResult (int resultCode, Intent data)` function for that. [More information is here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Please note that if you want to get data back to the Activity class then you should call `getActivity().startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)`

Or if you need to get data back to the fragment class itself just use `startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)`. It will return to `onActivityResult` in that fragment.

Comment: Alex, thanks a lot. I have tried the startActivityFroResult, but don't know how to implement onBackPressed. What code would I need to add there?

Comment: `onBackPressed` will automatically call when you press the back button. if you want to do that manually and avoid back button press you should call `super.onBackPressed(); `whenever you want.

Comment: Nice to hear that helps. Happy coding ;)

Comment: Thanks for the links too!

Answer (score 0):

Do like this...

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    Discover_Fragment fragmentS1 = new Discover_Fragment();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.containerView, fragmentS1).addToBackStack("fragBack");
                            .commit();
```

**Description for addToBackStack** - Add this transaction to the back stack. This means that the transaction will be remembered after it is committed, and will reverse its operation when later popped off the stack.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Tried your suggestion and I get exactly the same error ... Do I need to change the way I call the Activity from the Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int position, long arg3) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), EditThought.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });
```

these lines of code will work properly so use it

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting the error:

> when you want to return to the Fragment (Discover_Fragment) from
>   Activity EditThought, you used the following:
>
> ```
>                 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
>                 Discover_Fragment fragmentS1 = new Discover_Fragment();
>                 fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
>                         .replace(R.id.containerView, fragmentS1)
>                         .commit();
> ```
>
> Here, in above your code, have a look at `R.id.containerView`, which
>   is **not** from your **current** activity(**EditThought** Activity).

Now, Let's have a look at the solution:

> As **Alex Chengalan** told, you have to just call `onBackPressed()`
>   method instead of above code. And there you go!

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you very much. Yes, I could tell that the issue was that the containerView is not in EditThought Activity, but I really didn't know how to get back to the calling fragment. I forgot about the "super" part for the onBackPressed(), but using it works like a treat. Thanks for your time to explain what the issue is.